# python pointing to wrong ssl version

Tags: python

For a project i need to be using ssl 1.0.2. For some reason though python seems to be pointing to a wrong version.

i have installed pip pyOpenSSL and upgraded libssl-dev and python3-openssl, but these are my outputs:

```
pi@raspberrypi:/var/lib/dpkg/info $ openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017



pi@raspberrypi:/var/lib/dpkg/info $ python3
Python 3.4.2 (default, Oct 19 2014, 13:31:11) 
[GCC 4.9.1] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import ssl
>>> ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION
'OpenSSL 1.0.1t  3 May 2016'
```

Is there something i need to do the get python to point to the correct ssl version?

Comment: What is the problem with Raspberry Pi? Why do you use old versions? Does your project really need that? On my Raspberry Pi 3B+ with updated *Raspbian Stretch Lite 2018-06-27* I get with `python3 --version` -> `Python 3.5.3` and `openssl version` -> `OpenSSL 1.1.0f  25 May 2017`. That's all better than your versions.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your system has installed at least two different openssl versions. If that is the case, then there is a chance your openssl has been configured with alternatives to point to a different openssl version. You can simply confirm this by checking your /etc/alternatives directory if there is any ssl entry there that points to the unwanted version.